# SUM Data if Duplicate in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am having table with three columns  and may have duplicate data in it. what I am trying to do is if BATCH Column is having Duplicate Data then START_S and END_S should be according to below Example

```css
CREATE TABLE "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0_BATCH"
(
  "BATCH" character varying(128),
  "START_S" integer,
  "END_S" integer
)

INSERT INTO "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0_BATCH"(
            "BATCH", "START_S", "END_S")
    VALUES ('Batch 1_1',1451120920,1451121008),
    ('Batch 01_2',1451389014,1451389100),
('Batch 2_1',1451534680,1451534918),
('Batch 3_1',1451539145,1451539264),
('Parth_2',1451540990,1451541285),
('Parth_2',1451541676,1451542254)

SELECT "BATCH",((TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone 'epoch' + "START_S" * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone,
((TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone 'epoch' + "END_S" * INTERVAL '1 second') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone
FROM "DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0_BATCH"
```

Now as we can see Parth_2 is duplicate value so START_S and END_S for Parth_S should be

```
Parth_2      2015-12-31 11:19:50       2015-12-31 11:40:54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using GROUP BY and MIN/MAX aggregate functions (you can convert into date time later with below query in format you desire) like:

```
SELECT BATCH, MIN(START_S), MAX(END_S)
FROM DRL_FTO3_DI1_A0_BATCH
GROUP BY BATCH
```